# Python traverse through list and count items based on conditions

Tags: python, list

Lets say I have a Python list like following.

```
list2 = list('ABCDCBEGHGWAOUOV')
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'G', 'W', 'A', 'O', 'U', 'O', 'V']
```

While traversing the list at the 5th point I see 'C' is occurring again. So up to 'D' it is +4 and and the -1 since it come back.

```
A->B->C->D +3
C<-D -1
B<-C -1
B->E->G->H +3
G<-H -1
G->W +1
A<-W -4 etc...
```

I need to count steps for forward as positive and backward as negative. Any help for implementing this?

```
list1 = []
for item in list2:
    if item in list1:
        sum(1 for i in list2)
    else:
        list1.append(item)
```

Comment: Can you explain more verbosely what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: What's the expected output? A list of numbers? A score-like number? Waffles?

Comment: @Tobias i'm trying to understand some traversal patterns.

Comment: @timgeb : A list of scores

Comment: Is the `-1` because an item `is occurring again` or because an item is *less than* the previous item? Also, ```sum(1 for i in list2)``` does not *do* anything, it is not retained or used - what is its purpose?  For the input you provided, ```list2``` what do you want ```list1``` to look like?

Comment: @wwii : Please draw this traversal and see? I'll try to attach an image, thst is because at 'D' he is going back to 'C', I'm counting steps forward and backward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what's the expected output or what's the rule behind these numbers. This doesn't make much sens: `A<-W -4`. And this: `A->B->C->D +4`: do you count nodes? But here `C<-D -1` you count "steps", i.e. arrows? Anyway I'll give it a shot since it looks like a funny thing:

```
from itertools import islice

def get_it(list2):
    moves = []
    buffer = []
    prev = list2[0]

    for current in islice(list2, 1, None):
        el = 2 * (current > prev) - 1
        if buffer and el != buffer[0]:
            moves.append(sum(buffer))
            buffer = []
        buffer.append(el)
        prev = current

    if buffer:
        moves.append(sum(buffer))

    return moves
```

Comment: Hey freakish..Thanks for your concept, actually i'm trying to understand some traversal patterns :) If you draw the pattern in list2 and check, this question would not look silly as it is now:)